# How to move a view under another programatically?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a drawview, and I want to put it inside another view. To do this I have the following code:

```
DrawView drawview = new DrawView(this);
drawview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
views.addView(drawview);
```

It works fine, but what I want is that clicking a `button` change the order of the views, that one view(views) will be over another(drawview).

But I want that all time the two views are showed(the views are transparent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A qestion similar have been answered at

[How to put up or down a view programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997992/how-to-put-up-or-down-a-view-programatically)

Sorry to all to "duplicate" the question

Answer (score 2):

FrameLayout is the only way to place a view over the other. You can find a detailed documentation about FrameLayout [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).