# How to put up or down a view programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

I have a xml that the basic "skeleton" is

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <TextView>
            </TextView>
            <TextView>
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <DrawView>
            //The view that changes 1
        </DrawVIew>
        <EditText>
            //The view that changes 2
        </EditText>
    </FrameLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want is that using code the DrawView goes up or down, so sometimes you can use the DrawView and in other moments you can use the EditText, but ever the two views are showed.

How can I do that?

Comment: make the required views visible and invisible

Comment: What I want is that all time my views can be showed. The DrawView allows the user to paint in the screen and the EditText allows the user to write, so the two things are showed all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are placing both widgets inside a FrameLayout you can change its gravity like below:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams drawViewLayoutParams = drawView.getLayoutParams();
drawViewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

FrameLayout.LayoutParams editTextLayoutParams = editText.getLayoutParams();
editTextLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
```

Comment: I'm talking about to put a view over the other or to put one view under another, but  I will try it.

Comment: In this case you must call drawView.bringToFront() or editText.bringToFront(), or addView()/removeChild() methods from FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to remove all of the `FrameLayout`'s children and put them back in the order you need.

Or you can use another RelativeLayout and change the LayoutParams for the two Views